# Compile error when trying to access protected data member of base class?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

So I have a class address, a class name, and a class person that is derived from name.

```
class address
{
     public:
     address(char * street, char * zip);

     protected:
     char * street;
     char * zip;
};
class name
{
     public: 
     name( char * initial_name);

     protected:
     char * name;
     address a_address;
};
class person : public name
{
     public:
     person(char * name, char * street, char * zip);
}
```

the compile error is when I define the person constructor, it looks like this:

```
person::person(char * initial_name, char * street, char * zip): 
name(initial_name)
{
   a_address.address(street, zip);
}
```

when I try to access a_address it's telling me invalid use of address::address. Any clues to what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: You don't have a `address()` member function anywhere. You have a constructor defined. If you intended to call the constructor, you'd do it in the same way you initialized `name`

Comment: There's a class `name` which has a member `name`, which is a bad idea. That said, you can access the members but you can not initialize them. At the point the derived class  is constructed, the base class has been constructed and initialized already.

Comment: Why are you not using `std::string`

Comment: Too late to call a constructor. The object has already been instantiated. You can almost `a_address = address(street, zip);`, but you will run afoul of [The Rule of Three.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: Consider that there is an "is a" relationship between a person and a name as you have coded.
You should make it a property, so a person "has a" name.

Comment: A name has an address *and* a name, and a person *is* a name? I would expect a person to have a name and an address.

Answer (score 1):

> the compile error is when I define the person constructor,

You have a naming confusion here. You have a class called `name` which has a member called `name`. It has nothing to do with `protected` access to the member variable `name` in class `name`. You may want to change the variable to `a_name` or something else that is different than `name`.

> access a_address it's telling me invalid use of address::address

You cannot call a constructor on an object. That's what you are attempting to do with:

```
a_address.address(street, zip);
```

You need to create an appropriate constructor in `name` and pass the arguments from `person` to `name`.

Here's an updated version of your posted code that compiles and builds for me.

```
class address
{
   public:
      address(char * street, char * zip) : street(street), zip(zip) {}

   protected:
      char * street;
      char * zip;
};
class name
{
   public: 
      name(char * initial_name, char * street, char * zip);

   protected:
      char * a_name;
      address a_address;
};

name::name(char * initial_name, char * street, char * zip) :
      a_name(initial_name), a_address(street, zip)
{
}

class person : public name
{
   public:
      person(char * initial_name, char * street, char * zip);
};

person::person(char * initial_name, char * street, char * zip) : 
      name(initial_name, street, zip)
{
}

int main() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `name` class has a member variable named `name`.  Your code doesn't compile here because of that.

Also, your `person` class needs a semicolon after the class declaration.

And you could set `a_address` like this:

```
a_address = address(street, zip);
```

Comment: `a_address = address(street, zip);` maybe you can do this. You will wind up with two objects pointing to the same `street` and `zip` and possibly a memory leak or Rule of Three violation.

Comment: I disagree.  He doesn't reserve any memory at all for those.

He should rewrite everything, but my answer was intended to help him past the compiler errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the member variable `a_address`, as it is `protected` in the base class; but you cannot access the member variables inside the class `address`, as you did not derive from `address`. For the class `address`, you are a stranger, and you have no access to its `protected` members.

Your structure is not very object oriented, that’s why you run into such troubles. The class `address` should have a constructor, which you call with its details, and `address` itself handles the assignemnets to its internal members. If you access members from outside the class, you use them only as simple data structures. That is fine, but it is not object oriented coding, and if you want to work that way , you should change `class` to `struct` (as this is exactly the difference between the two), and remove the protected.

Comment: This answer is irrelevant. Asker is not trying to directly access `address`'s innards.